# redis hyperloglog.pfmerge inconsistency

Tags: redis, hyperloglog

```
pfadd today, item1, item2, ..., itemM
pfadd tomorrow, item1, item2, ..., itemN
pfadd so-on, item1, item2, ..., itemP
...

pfcount today      // returns  8000
pfcount tomorrow   // returns  9000
pfcount so-on      // returns 13000

pfcount today, tomorrow, so-on
                   // returns 28000
```

Although the items are approximately the same **the cardinality differs too much, why is that?** I was expecting around cardinality of 12000 after pfcount for all the days.

---

```
date    pfadd      pfcount

10-15   40.754     205.322
10-14   40.055     196.249
10-13   39.877     193.830
10-12   13.079     18.151
```

Also, from the above data, I have counted when pfadd returns 1 in the pfadd column above, and also execute pfcount above. **Why pfadd and pfcount is so different?**

Comment: PFCOUNT for multiple keys will return the sum of counts whereas it appears you want to use PFMERGE - have you tried that?

Comment: No it does not according to the documentation: When called with multiple keys, returns the approximated cardinality of the union of the HyperLogLogs passed, by internally merging the HyperLogLogs stored at the provided keys into a temporary hyperLogLog.

Comment: What do you mean by "_the items are approximately the same_"? Do you add the same elements to each key? Or the _number_ of elements you add is the same? Also, do you use `pfadd` with multiple elements?

Comment: What do you mean by 'do you use pfadd with multiple elements'? Approximately means adding almost the same items to hyperlogged vars.